# $L^2(\Omega)$ Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In most books on mathematics, when discussing the space $L^2(\Omega)$ of square-integrable functions defined on $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$, it is often assumed that $\Omega$  is a connected *open* set. Do any technical problems arise if assume $\Omega$ to be a closed set?

Comment: Absolutely not. $\Omega$ can be any measurable set.

Comment: However, as soon as any notion of differentiability appears, it's best to be working in an open set.

Comment: Whether or not any technical problems arise would depend on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was wondering why so many books explicitly assume $\Omega$ to be open instead of simply measurable, as mentioned by Kavi above.  It wouldn't hurt to define the Hilbert space in a slightly more general setting, especially in sections where only examples of Hilbert spaces are given.